# Configurable Product with variants

Tags: configurable-product

I have a product that is available in different variants and they are as follow:

- Type: Leather
- Form: Round, or Rectangular
- Position: Up, or Down
- Size: Small, Medium, Large, XL, and XXL
- Quantity: Customer will enter the desired quantity
- Prices: Depending on quantity

All of the above options should be listed in the front end as Drop Down but if customer chooses the form 'Rectangular', then the 'Position' option should not be shown (hide or disappear) in the front end as an option but the rest would show!

Your help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with configurable products **or** in default Magento. Configurable options must all be selected for checkout. If you need a custom set of options selected, you need to use `Custom Options`. Additionally, Magento doesn't feature allowing dependent option selection.

Some ways to achieve this..

1. Make simple products with custom options (you might not be able to do this depending on how you manage SKUs). Create your own extension where you write some JS that manages the dropdown custom options.
2. Try searching a third-party extension. There is one such extension out there ("dependend custom options"), but I don't recommend it.

Option 1 is **way** better.